# FA that accepts only those words that have an even number of substrings cdc?

Tags: computer-science, automata

I take this question as it could accept cdccdc,cdccdccdccdc,dddcdccdc,etc. I feel that I coveed all the even loops of cdccdc but I am stuck trying to figure out how to add in c* and d* in the mix of strings so that it is like ddddcccdccdcdddcc

this is what I have so far
[image]

thanks

Update

Yes, I have to have it accept even lengthed cdc so "cdccdccdccdc" is acceptable also would be "ddcdccdcddddcccdccdcdd"

Comment: I think when it's that far into CS territory, you should just post on [cs.se].

Comment: Should the FA accept $cdcdc$? The substring $cdc$ occurs at exactly two places in this string, but the two substrings overlap.

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29639/755.  Please don't cross-post.  (@Thursday, when suggesting that people post elsewhere, you might want to remind them not to cross-post, but rather to flag it for moderator attention and ask the moderator to migrate it.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following:

[image]

The formatting isn't perfect. But the idea is to loop until you find a $c$, then try to find a $cdc$. If you don't find the correct next character, go back and start over. Once you find a $cdc$, move to the other (left) half of the diagram and do it all again. Once you've found the second $cdc$, accept. The rest of the string is irrelevant. If you run out of characters before accept, you fail.

Comment: I think he wants to accept $cdccdccdccdc$, for example.

Comment: Yes, I have to have it accept even lengthed cdc so "cdccdccdccdc" is acceptable also would be "ddcdccdcddddcccdccdcdd"

Comment: Well, then all you need to do is to add self-referencing $c$ and $d$ links to the accept state.